# Jquery - .text() , .html() not working on IE8

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

Here is the code and jsfiddle link . I tried .text and .html both functions. But both not working on IE8. Could any one provide me the solution for IE ? ( I googled and people seems to have similar kind of problems , but couldn't get solution)  Thank You

http://jsfiddle.net/3eaGL/

```
  <div class="controls">       
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
                <input name="MySecurity[my_education]" id="MySecurity_my_education" type="hidden" value="0" />                            
                <button type="button" class="btn" value="2" display="Private">P</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn" value="1" display="Friends">F</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn" value="0" display="All ( Public )">A</button>
            </div>   
            <text class="mySecurityDisplay"></text>  
       </div>  




$("button[display]").bind('click', function(){
                    var buttonValue=this.value;
                    $(this).siblings("input[type=hidden]").val(buttonValue);
                    $(this).parent().next().text($(this).attr( 'display' ));
                 });
```

Comment: is there any error occurs? or it just doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks Mahan . Here is the error I am getting "Message: Unexpected call to method or property access."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the `<text>` tag. This isn't a valid HTML tag. IE below version 9 interpretes unknown tags in this way: `<text class="mySecurityDisplay"></text>` will become `<text class="mySecurityDisplay"/><text/>` an so you can't insert any content inside it.

Just write `<div class="mySecurityDisplay"></div>`, this will work.

Comment: I wondered why some one down voted your answer :( But not that was not me

Comment: someone maybe to improve the own answer... kindergarten

Comment: you gave the answer first , so I selected yours .

Answer (score 7):

The issue is this:

```
<text class="mySecurityDisplay"></text>
```

IE8 doesn't render unknown tags, therefore jQuery doesn't select your element, the issue is not related to `html` or `text` method. Use a valid tag instead and your code will work.

Comment: Thank You for that . <span> helped me

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it working the problem was the `<text>` element

http://jsfiddle.net/3eaGL/7/

the Jquery created an instance object after selecting the `<text>` element but because its not a valid HTML tag, the Jquery object will not return any methods for your disposal.

Its like your trying to do a `val()` to a `<span>` element but is only valid in html form elements.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether you have valid html, There could be mismatched tags.
2. Try using append instead of the html method.